# Why doesn't C# support arrays larger than 2GB?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core

Why can't I use arrays bigger than 2 GB? Is there a deeper problem or is it simply implemented on `int`?

It seems that .net core throws an exception if I try to allocate a array with 10 billion elements:

```
int[] bigArray = new int[10_000_000_000]; // throws exception
```

Comment: I don't know... But that will be an ugly array.

Comment: Implementation of array from [Reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs)

Comment: Your question title is wrong. You can create arrays larger than 2gb. How did you calculate you are allocating 2 gb? From my calculation your array should be approximately 3 gb.

Comment: Because Lenght property returns Int32, and it's maximum value is about 2 billions. However there is LongLength property